# How to tell how many pages will be printed using java with out dialog box

Tags: java, printing

Hi all i am using java printer api, so far i have all the settings configured below :

```
aset.add(new Copies(p));
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
```

this configures the settings for the printers, but is it possible to know how many pages will be printed ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701644/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-pages-to-be-printed

Comment: Thanks thats great, but i was hoping for a solution that could be done in the code and does not require a print dialog