# Get number of pages from print dialog in java

Tags: java, printing

I am creating a simple app using java that will print a file. I need to get the number of pages the user wants to print prior to printing. I tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701644/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-pages-to-be-printed), but it doesnt work for me. Is there any way to use job.printDialog and get the number of pages from the dialog box?

I am not that good at java so it would be very good for me if you could provide example code.

Is there any way to achieve it by using the desktop class?

Comment: What is not working? Are you facing exceptions/Errors?

Comment: Duplicate question : [How can I get the total number of pages to be printed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701644/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-pages-to-be-printed)