# Get total number of pages to be printed using java.awt.Desktop?

Tags: java, printing

I wish to get the total number of pages to be printed in my program. I'm using java.awt.Desktop class. Here is my code for the printing part-

```
public class PrintJob {

    public static void print(String str) {
        try {
            Desktop desktop = null;
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            }

            desktop.print(new File(str));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid file type.");
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to get the total number of pages to be printed. How can i do it?

Comment: Looking at the limited `Desktop` API, I'd say you can't. It may be possible if you use another Java printing API, see [How can I get the total number of pages to be printed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701644/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-pages-to-be-printed?rq=1) for example.

Comment: I don't see how you could with `Desktop`, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3717177/1276341) explains a way without it.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks a lot for your help, but sadly, i'm new to java. I've already tried the method you mentioned. In that way, i get the page numbers, but i cant print any files. Can anyone please tell me how to print file of doc, txt and jpg types? Then i could integrate the two methods. Thanks again for your time.